# Can you say "more environmentally friendly ways"?

Tags: grammar

English is not my first language and I'm trying to translate a text from Swedish to English for my English class.

I'm wondering if it is correct to use "more environmentally friendly ways" in this sentence:

> We need to find cheaper and more environmentally friendly ways to produce the fuel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks okay to me. I might write it as "more environmentally-friendly".

Comment: No hyphen in environmentally friendly (no hyphen after words ending in "-ly")

Answer (score 2):

I prefer **eco-friendly** or **green**.  Environmentally-friendly just seems too long.

Comment: I prefer those, too.  But, you'd agree that environmentally-friendly is perfectly acceptable (and used), right?

Comment: @DavidM - I don't have any problems with it and see it.  I see greener used more now.

Comment: Just wanted to make sure that wasn't lost on the OP.  You and I are native speakers, and it's obvious to us.

Comment: Wouldn't those two words be considered slightly informal?